# Add shared permission and get public link of the uploaded file using GoogleDriveApi v3 in C# .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api

I am trying to get public shareable link of the uploaded files to GoogleDrive using GoogleDriveApi v3. I am able to upload the files and get `FileId`. I am not able to add Permission and shareable link to the uploaded files. I have searched numerous answers on the Internet  and StackOverflow, but did not anything that would help me solve the problem. I have tried solutions that were provided for Java and Python, but I am getting error:

> `Google.GoogleApiException: 'The service drive has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is Forbidden. The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable.'`

Here's my code:

```cs
public async Task UploadFileAsync(Stream file, string fileName, string fileMime, string folder, string fileDescription)
{
    DriveService driveService = GetService();
    var fileMetaData = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
    {
        Name = filename, Description = fileDescription, MimeType = fileMime, Parents = new string[] { folder },
    };

    var request = driveService.Files.Create(fileMetaData, file, fileMime);
    request.Fields = "id, webContentLink";

    var response = await request.UploadAsync(cancellationToken);

    if (response.Status != UploadStatus.Completed)
        throw response. Exception;

    var permission = new Permission { AllowFileDiscovery = true, Id = "id, webContentLink", Type = "anyone", Role = "reader" };
    var createRequest = driveService.Permissions.Create(permission, request.ResponseBody.Id);
    createRequest.Fields = "id, webContentLink";
    await createRequest.ExecuteAsync();

    Debug.WriteLine("Link: " + request.ResponseBody.WebContentLink);
}
```

I am getting the link in the statement `request.ResponseBody.WebContentLink`, but the permissions are not set on the file. Hence the file is not shared and the link does not work. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working after correcting the `Permission` initialization. Seems that Permission.Id is not writeable (hence the error `The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable.`). Thus, removed assignment of some value to `Permission.Id`.

Hence the correct way would be

```cs
var permission = new Permission { AllowFileDiscovery = true, Type = "anyone", Role = "reader" };
var fileId = request.ResponseBody.Id;
await driveService.Permissions.Create(permission, fileId).ExecuteAsync();
```

Hence, in this way we can set permissions on the uploaded file and make it shareable through code. Rest of the code is correct. Further we will get downloadable link using `request.ResponseBody.WebContentLink`.

Answer (score 0):

The sharable link created through the google drive web application is not something that you can create or get via the google drive API.

The WebView link at the download links can only be used by someone who has permissions on the file

so you will need to add the user as reader for the file if you want them to be able to use that link

## API flow to upload a file and grant access to a user.

Create a file via the [file.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) method uploading the file.

Then preform a [permissions.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create) adding the user who you would like to be able to have access to download the file.

Then do a [file.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) to get the WebContentLink and the user should be able to access the file via their google drive account.

Comment: I have added `permission = new Permission { ... Role = "reader" }`. Is it not sufficient? If not, how can I add user as a reader? I am getting the downloadable link by `request.ResponseBody.WebContentLink`. Just the problem is that I cannot make the uploaded file shareable. When I get the downloadable link, I cannot download it until I manually enable sharing by going to the website. After that, I can download the file by using the link that I got using `request.ResponseBody.WebContentLink`. The problem is only making the file shareable through code. Can you provide code to make file shareble?

Comment: Web content link gives the user access to view the file in their google drive account.   Its not a download link.

Comment: WebContentLink provides the download link. I have solved the issue and added my own answer. We can set the shared permissions through code using Google Drive API and also get the download link of the uploaded file. Please check my answer. Hope it helps someone. BTW, thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Download link is only there for files that are not of google mime types.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get that. Are Google Mime types different than normal Mime types. Can you tell me in which scenarios my code will not work?